# PostgreSQL: date/time field value out of range

Tags: postgresql, import, csv, date-format

Software:

```
Linux cjz-eshop1-p 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

I am getting errors due to CSV import into the database on my server.

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Price 244385 ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "30.06.2020"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
  Position: 160
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Price 244386 ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "30.06.2020"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
  Position: 160
```

But on my local system, the import is working.

I tried almost everything regarding this issue, but no luck (I drew mostly from here).

Any ideas to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Import is done by `java`. I believe it is not important, because on my local computer, it is working with same OS and same configuration. And as you can see, when I try `select` related to date (as @Laurenz helped me), it is ok.

```
postgres@cjz-eshop1-p:~$ psql
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT '30.06.2020'::date;
    date    
------------
 30.06.2020
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Before, it was not possible. Do you want some more details?

**UPDATE 2**

````
                    if (body[5].length() != 0) {
                        akc_from = "'" + body[5] + "'";
                    } else {
                        akc_from = "null";
                    }

                    if (body[6].length() != 0) {
                        akc_to = "'" + body[6] + "'";
                    } else {
                        akc_to = "null";
                    }

                    if (body[7].length() != 0) {
                        akc_type = body[7];
                    } else {
                        akc_type = "null";
                    }

                    insertPriceCommand = "insert into stg_price(art_no,store_no,sell_pr,akc_price,akc_from,akc_to,akc_type,run_id,proc_flag,proc_note) values(" + art_no + "," + store_no + "," + sell_pr + "," + akc_price + "," + akc_from + "," + akc_to + "," + akc_type + "," + run_id + ",0,null)";
//                System.out.println(insertPriceCommand);
```
````

Answer (score 5):

Follow the hint and adjust your [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting appropriately.

The parameter consists of two parts: the output style and the expected ordering of day, month and year.

With US settings, parsing `30.06.2020` causes an error:

```
SET datestyle = US, MDY;

SELECT '30.06.2020'::date;

ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "30.06.2020"
LINE 1: SELECT '30.06.2020'::date;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

This is because there are only 12 months in a year.

You should probably use this setting:

```
SET datestyle = GERMAN, DMY;

SELECT '30.06.2020'::date;

    date    
------------
 30.06.2020
(1 row)
```

You can use the `options` connection parameter to set `datestyle` when you connect.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already before, but error persist.

Comment: What is your `datestyle` setting, and what is the data type of the column that is to receive the value?

Comment: Seems configuration is not saving, after logout from psql console and login back, settings are `US, MDY` again, not `GERMAN, DMY`.

Comment: Sure. Set the environment variable `PGDATESTYLE` as indicated in my extended answer to set the default for all clients that use `libpq`.

Comment: And how can I set this environment var? In `/etc/postgres/12/main/environment`? I tried, but no changes. And is there way to set permanent `datestyle` with `SET`?

Comment: Set in bash under postgres user, in DB it is OK when I tried SET `datestyle = GERMAN, DMY;`, but when I run import, error persist.

Comment: Well, perhaps it would help if you [edit] the question and tell us *how exactly* you import the file.

Comment: Question updated, do you want some detailed info?

Comment: Ok, with JDBC you have to set the parameter differently. What is the exact statement that causes the error?

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late answer. Question updated.

Comment: That should work fine. Can you ascertain from your Java code that `datestyle` is set correctly?

Comment: I cannot parse this: "*there is no such as setup*" The data type `date` is fine.

Comment: I mean there is no `datestyle` defined in code, so I suppose it works with default value from DB? And it is quite strange that on my local import is working.

Comment: The default must be different. So change your Java code to explicitly set `datestyle`.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. And I'll try it on another server. Thanks.

Comment: I tried on another server, but no luck, same issue. I don't understand, on my local import is OK and I see no difference between local and server. I am quite lost. :/ What can I do for identify differencies between my local and remote server related to this issue?

Comment: I tell you once and for all: this only depends on the setting of `datestyle`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but configuration for datestyle for DB and java is absolutely same (on the server and on the local), but on the server is not working, on local it is working. All is same.

Comment: Note that setting the parameter on the server is not good enough. You need to set it in the actual database session in which you load the data.